# Phone call support with Accessebility Services

Tags: android

How can I use the Accessibility Services in Android to recognize when there is a call coming in? I would like to build an app that provides some call-handling options and support, e.g. read out phone number...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Accessebility Services for that. First capture the suitable Broadcast Intnet then retrieve the call number and then read it using TTS.

read more: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html